# Как изменить стили элемента

Tags: javascript

```js
var slider = document.getElementsByTagName("article");
slider[4].style.Zindex = 10;
console.log(slider);
```

```css
article{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<article>article text0</article>
<article>article text1</article>
<article>article text2</article>
<article>article text3</article>
<article>article text4</article>
```

Подскажите как залезть в стиль и изменить z-index на 10
Стили не в отдельном файле, а в файле HTML

Comment: вместо `Zindex` скорее всего надо `zIndex`

Comment: попробуйте `slider[4].style.zIndex = 10` . По общему правилу,  дефис в названии свойства дает заглавную букву

Comment: Спасибо. А куда тут нажать что-бы отблагодарить?

Comment: Принять ответ можно если будет дан ответ. Мы же писали комментарии к вопросу. Сейчас оформлю комментарий как ответ  - сможете попрактиковаться в принятии ответов ;)

Answer (score 1):

По общему правилу, дефис в названии свойства дает заглавную букву.
Попробуйте `slider[4].style.zIndex = 10`